# find every language in url with regex

Tags: regex

I'm not that bad with regex, but I don't know the cool features. because of that I need some help for something that sounds simple, but suddenly it isn't.

I have a url that contains a language: https://localhost/projekt/fi/hallo

But sometimes, there are more than one language in the url like that (extrem example): https://localhost/projekt/de/en/dk/fr/fi/hallo

How can I detect every language or just the last one + the others in one group?

It could be that simple: `(\/[a-z]{2}\/)` but that matches just every second language, because of the second slash. Is there a way to tell regex to use the last slash again?

Comment: Use `/\/([a-z]{2})(?![^\/])/g` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLMUzt/1)). Or just split with `/` and filter out those that do not match `/^[a-z]{2}$/`

Comment: wow thank you very much, I know about the lookahead, but I didn't know how to use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\/([a-z]{2})(?![^\/])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLMUzt/1). The value you need will be in Group 2.

**Details**

- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([a-z]{2})` - Capturing group 1: 2 lowercase letters
- `(?![^\/])` - no non-`/` char is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.